# How to transform Appearance value or slider value in Manipulate?

Tags: animation

My code is more involved, but my question boils down to this. I have a list of values where each entry represents the x-position of a particle at time $t$.  These values are calculated by a finite difference scheme and the output is a list $pos=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$,where $x_i$ represents the position at time $t_i=i*\delta$ and $\delta=0.1$.  Code that illustrates my question is

```
pos= {0., 0.64, 1.8688, 3.6393, 5.90815, 8.63549};
n=Length[pos];
Manipulate[pos[[k]], {{k, 1, "t"}, 1, n, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
Alignment -> Center, ImageMargins -> Large, ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

On the left side of the slider I have label $t$. On the other end of the slider the values of k are displayed.  Can some tell me how to change this code so that rather than "k" being displayed, .1k is displayed?

Comment: `Manipulate[pos[[Round[10 k]]], {{k, .1, "t"}, .1, .1 n, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Alignment -> Center, ImageMargins -> Large, ControlPlacement -> Top]`